# Datagrid change a cell value if it's default(dateTime)

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

i've got a datagrid that contains two datetime columns.
The first one is a start dateTime and it's always set with the DateTime.Now on create. The second is the deadline and may be set with the default(DateTime), because it's optionnal.

I'd like to display a clear cell if "deadline.Equals(default(DateTime));" without changing the Item.deadline.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dtg_Todo.Items.Count; i++)
{
   var row = dtg_Todo.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i) as DataGridRow;
   Todo elem = (Todo)row.Item;
   if (elem.DateEcheance.Equals(default(DateTime))){
                dtg_Todo.Columns[5].GetCellContent(row).
   }
}
```

From this point I can't figure out what I can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your second DateTime is optional, have you considered using a `Nullable<DateTime>`? That way you can set it to `null` by default, and your DataGrid's cells will look empty when the value is set to `null`.

For more info about Nullable Types, check this article in the MSDN: [Nullable Types (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx)